# Use dplyr::select's where with base R grepl and anonymus function

Tags: r, select, dplyr

There is a very similar question here: [How to select columns based on grep in dplyr::tibble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314777/how-to-select-columns-based-on-grep-in-dplyrtibble)

However I think that the `select_if` was superseeded with `select(where())`.

I know that I can do the following and it works:

```
# select all columns with three characters
mtcars %>% 
  select(
    matches("^[a-zA-Z]{3}$")
  )
```

But I can also use an anonymus function (here over all the column values and not the names) to select columns.

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(
    where(function(x)sum(is.na(x)) == 0)
  )
```

So I thought I could use an anonymus function and `grepl` to select columns. And this does not work:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(
    where(
      function(x) grepl("^[a-zA-Z]{3}$", x)
    )
  )
```

How could I make this work? I mean I could always use the `matches` helper. But I would just like to understand how to use

`select(where())` statement over the names of the dataframe and not over all the values in a column.

**Update**

This works:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(
      which(grepl("^[a-zA-Z]{3}$", names(.)))
  )
```

But I am not sure if there isn't a better way;)

Comment: `matches()` is designed to detect column names, but `where()` to detect column values, and hence `where()` cannot capture column names.

Comment: `where()` is not intended to be used with column names, but only with values of the columns. Really, the most obvious solution her is `select(mtcars, grep("^\\w{3}$", names(mtcars))) `, or even better - a base solution given by @Quinten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use `grep()` with `select()` without the `where()` function.

```r
mtcars %>% 
  select(grep("^[a-zA-Z]{3}$", names(.)))
```

Your initial attempt didn't work because in this code:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  select(
    where(
      function(x) grepl("^[a-zA-Z]{3}$", x)
    )
  )
```

the `x` in the `where()` function are the values of the variable and not the name of the variable.  That's why it works if you did something like `where(is.numeric)` works - because it is substituting the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

`Base` R option:

```
mtcars[grepl("^[a-zA-Z]{3}$", names(mtcars))]
```

Output:

```
                     mpg cyl
Mazda RX4           21.0   6
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6
Datsun 710          22.8   4
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8
Valiant             18.1   6
Duster 360          14.3   8
Merc 240D           24.4   4
Merc 230            22.8   4
Merc 280            19.2   6
Merc 280C           17.8   6
Merc 450SE          16.4   8
Merc 450SL          17.3   8
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8
Fiat 128            32.4   4
Honda Civic         30.4   4
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4
Toyota Corona       21.5   4
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8
AMC Javelin         15.2   8
Camaro Z28          13.3   8
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4
Lotus Europa        30.4   4
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6
Maserati Bora       15.0   8
Volvo 142E          21.4   4
```

Comment: thanks!:) But I wanted to use it with `dplyr::select(where(....`